# Rest api Upload attachments not working for multiple uploads

Tags: office-365, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using Rest api to upload the attachments

```
function uploadattachment(itemId, listname) {
    if ($("#ticketAttachments")[0].files.length > 0) {
        $($("#ticketAttachments")[0].files).each(function (i, file) {
                getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: buffer,
                        processData: false,
                        headers: {
                            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                            "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            if ($("#ticketAttachments")[0].files.length == i + 1) {
                                RefreshPage();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
    }
    else {
        RefreshPage();
    }
};
```

This one works for uploading single file, but when I have 2 or more files, it goes to the error part giving the below error

> "{" error ": {" code ":" - 2130246326,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException "," message ": {" lang ":" en-US ","
>   value ":" Registration conflict \ n \ nYour changes conflict with
>   those made by another user at the same time. If you want your changes
>   to be applied, click Previous in your web browser, refresh the page
>   and resubmit them. "}}}"

Not sure what I have missed. Can someone please advise?

Comment: You can check https://blogs.ibs.com/2016/02/23/uploading-multiple-attachments-in-sharepoint-with-one-input/

Comment: how about also adding `If-Match:*` in the header and checking ?